# Selector to match text exactly?

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

Jsoup contains selectors `:contains(text)` that will match `thetextishere`.  What if I only want exact matches, not substrings? That is, what selector can I use to match `text` but not `superstringoftextishere`?

Comment: Take a look at answer I just posted. It explains how to select specific exact words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

> `:matches(regex):` find elements whose text matches the specified regular expression; e.g. `div:matches((?i)login)`

So I'd think you could use this:

```
:matches(^text$)
```

Comment: Did you try that? I already tried it and it returns nothing.  Prob. because the regex engine wants newlines when it sees those symbols.

Comment: I was wrong - this does work! The reason my tests failed was that initially, `"p:matches(text)"` would match `<p><span>text</span></p>`, but, with exact match, `"p:matches(^text$)"` returns nothing; you need to do `"p span:matches(^text$)"`